# flutter emojis: I have build amn app and i want to use emoji in my text, but the displayed message not as good as I expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have built an app and I want to use emojies in my text, but the displayed message is not as good as I expected.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_emoji/flutter_emoji.dart';

 var heart  = Emoji('heart', '❤️');
 Text(" Play me $heart",);
```

and this is the displayed message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```dart
Text("Play me ${heart.code}");
```